# css :not pseudo class not working

Tags: html, css

```css
:not( .banner-nav-not ) .banner-nav a{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
  <div class="banner-nav clearfix">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="banner-nav-not" href="#">how we can help? <span>what we offer</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">mobile technologies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">corporate training</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">online marketing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">graphic design</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I want to select every "a" tag except class".banner-nav-not".

Comment: `.banner-nav a:not(.banner-nav-not)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a wrong order .change that `.banner-nav a:not( .banner-nav-not )`

```css
.banner-nav a:not( .banner-nav-not ) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-nav clearfix">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="banner-nav-not" href="#">how we can help? <span>what we offer</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">mobile technologies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">corporate training</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">online marketing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">graphic design</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```